# Regular expression, need to fix

Tags: regex

I tried to write regular expression that extract value between `<ul class=\"theatre\">` and `</ul>`

I wrote that regex:

```
<ul class=\"theatre\">(\s)*[<>/ =":\._,)(a-zA-Z0-9(\s)ĄĘŚĆŻŹŁÓĆŃąęśćżźłóćń\-]+</ul>
```

My question is, how to modify this regular expression to get result ended by first encountered `</ul>` tag? Here's my example:

> http://regexr.com?33j92

It should by ended before `<div class=`

I know that regex shouldn't been used for html (I have read about that before on SO). I just have to do it, to understand why it's not ended on first `</ul>` and how I can fix it.

Comment: Add a `?` after the last `+` to make it non-greedy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use

```
 <ul class="theatre">([\s\S]+?)<\/ul>
```

For example, in Javascript, you could do

```
var str = '<ul class="theatre"> bananas </ul>',
    m = str.match( /<ul class="theatre">([\s\S]+?)<\/ul>/ );

if ( m ) {
    console.log( m[1] );    // " bananas "
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the lazy ? modifier and use the dot-all flag to match the dot (matches any character) across end-of-lines. The "global" (multi-match) flag should not be set

Check this regexp, checking only the dot-all checkbox in your [web regexp test](http://regexr.com?33j92):

```
<ul\s.*?</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
<ul.*?>(.*?)</ul>
```